# slimで inputmaskの使い方

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim

Ruby on RailsにAdminLTEを適用して開発をしています。
今回AdminLTEで使いたい部分は下記のコードです。

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Date masks:</label>

    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" data-inputmask="'alias': 'dd/mm/yyyy'" data-mask>
    </div>
    <!-- /.input group -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.form group -->
</div>
```

上記のコードをslimに変えて使いたいです。
下記は自分のコードです。

```
div.box-body
  = form_for @book do |f|
    div.form-group
      .field
        = f.label :出版日
```

= f.text_fieldを利用したslimコードに直していただきたいんです。
特に

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-inputmask="'alias': 'dd/mm/yyyy'" data-mask>
```

のdata-inputmask="'alias': 'dd/mm/yyyy'" data-maskをどうslimに書けばいいかわからないのでよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 質問はslimへの変換方法ではなくf.text_fieldの使い方ですか？

Answer (score 1):

slim への変換に関しては、html から、slim への変換サイトがあるようです。

https://html2slim.herokuapp.com/

コレを使うと、下記になりました。

```
.form-group
  label Date masks:
  .input-group
    .input-group-addon
      i.fa.fa-calendar
    input.form-control data-inputmask=("'alias': 'dd/mm/yyyy'") data-mask="" type="text" /
  /! /.input group
/! /.form group
```